# npm unable to fetch Meteorite

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, meteorite

With nodejs v0.10.22 and npm v1.3.14, I tried installing meteorite as shown below:

```
$ npm install meteorite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite/-/meteorite-0.6.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite/-/meteorite-0.6.16.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite/-/meteorite-0.6.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite/-/meteorite-0.6.16.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite/-/meteorite-0.6.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite/-/meteorite-0.6.16.tgz
npm ERR! network socket hang up
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

**Question:** Is this a common error? How can we fix this?

Comment: I think NPM's registry is having issues right now.

Comment: How can we use `npm` to pull packages from a mirror of the NPM registry?

Answer (score 0):

NPM was down, you can use an NPM mirror if you have one available.

```
npm set registry <registry-location>
```

You'll have to setup a mirror or find someone who has.

When you want to reset to normal:

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```